# Installing Gnatstudio on RPI 4 v7

Tags: gtk, ada, gnat

When executing ./configure for Gnatstudio I receive the following error.  I have searched for references related to this but can't anything associated with it.  Gprconfig has been configured without incident.

checking that your gnat compiler works with a simple example... GNAT-TEMP-000001.TMP:108:11: undefined attribute "bindfile_option_substitution"
GNAT-TEMP-000001.TMP:109:11: undefined attribute "bindfile_option_substitution"
gprbuild: processing of configuration project "/tmp/GNAT-TEMP-000001.TMP" failed

Locating variable "bindfile_option_substitution."  Don't know where this is located.

Comment: I would just give up now. The chances of you successfully building GS are practically zero. If you do wish to persevere, then you will have to find the git versions of all the other libs that AdaCore have compiled the released against, and you may find that some of those also need exact git versions of sub libs to be able to be built. If you try and use the latest git release for GS, then forget it, I doubt you will be able to find versions of the other libs to be able to build it. The non-released versions are just a piece of junk that AdaCode have no interest in fixing, ever.

Comment: You should be able to install GNAT, gprbuild, and GNAT Studio using [Alire](https://alire.ada.dev/). You can also use the [AppImage](https://github.com/AdaCore/gnatstudio/releases/download/gnatstudio-cr-20230501/GNAT_Studio-x86_64.AppImage) release from AdaCore under Linux.